# De-duplicating transaction records

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am a bit stuck! I have data, like the below.

[image]

I need to calculate the sum of frequency between each customer. In the above, FROM customer1 TO customer2 should be summed with FROM customer2 TO customer1 - like below.

It doesn't matter which direction the message went in; I just need to sum all communication between customer1 and customer2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `greatest` and `least` functionality as follows:

```
select least(from,to) as from, greatest(from,to) as to, sum(frequency) as freq
  from your_Table
 group by least(from,to), greatest(from,to)
```

If greatest and least is not supported in your version then you can use the `case..when` also.

```
select case when from > to then to else from end as from, 
       case when from > to then from else to end as to, 
       sum(frequency) as freq
  from your_Table
 group by case when from > to then to else from end, 
          case when from > to then from else to end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try sorting the From To

```
WITH tab AS
(SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 2)
, ('Customer 2', 'Customer 1', 4)
, ('Customer 3', 'Customer 1', 4)
) a ([From], [To], [Frequency])
)
SELECT IIF([From] > [To], [To], [From]) [From]
     , IIF([From] > [To], [From], [To]) [To]
     , SUM([Frequency]) Frequency
From tab
GROUP BY IIF([From] > [To], [To], [From])
       , IIF([From] > [To], [From], [To])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by a sorted array:

```
select 
    sort_array(array(`from`, `to`))[0] `from`,
    sort_array(array(`from`, `to`))[1] `to`,
    sum(frequency)
from mytable
group by sort_array(array(`from`, `to`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that two map() with the same key-value pairs but in different order are equal, because maps are unordered by definition, you can exploit this property to aggregate frequency.

Demo with your data example:

```
with mytable as(
select stack (3,
'Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 2,
'Customer 2', 'Customer 1', 4,
'Customer 3', 'Customer 1', 4  
) as (`from`, `to` , frequency)
)

select map_keys(vmap)[0] as `from`,  map_keys(vmap)[1] as `to`, frequency
from
(
select map(`from`, 1, `to`, 1) vmap, sum(frequency) frequency
 from mytable group by map(`from`, 1, `to`, 1) 
)s;
```

Result:

```
from          to              frequency
Customer 2    Customer 1      6
Customer 3    Customer 1      4
```